# The debugger Dockerfile' is invalid

Tags: dockerfile, visual-studio-2019

Hi I am using Visual Studio 2019 and created blank Web Application Project and added docker file. (Docker Container is Linux) and when I execute my project in 'Release' mode I face following errors

The debugger path 'C:\Users\Myuser\vsdbg\vs2017u5' for Dockerfile 'D:\Users\Myuser\Source\Repos\Practice\Practice\Dockerfile' is invalid.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing similar issue.
Check for the errors in the output window. If there are errors related to policy, then run below commands.

Launch powershell with administrator privilege and execute below commands

1. Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
2. Set-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell -Name ExecutionPolicy -Value ByPass

After executing above commands, try to run the application.

Comment: I executed second command (#2), problem is resolved. When execute #1 command, following exception show:  Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by
a policy defined at a more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective
execution policy of AllSigned. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings....